# Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS)

Tags: html, jsp, veracode

I am trying to get the server details for my webservice application

```
<tr>
 <td style="text-align: right">Remote Host Name:</td>
 <td><%= request.getRemoteHost() + ":" + request.getRemotePort()%></td>
</tr>
```

I recently run the veracode and I am having an issue with `getRemoteHost()` Any suggestions on how to prevent it?

Comment: Please be more specific : what issue do you have ?

Comment: I am new to veracode scanning and when i run my application in it. I got the XSS flaw for getRemoteHost().The code will display the remote host name and it's not used for any other operations. So, I am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: This probably means that if there is a host named <script> ... , your function just naively echoes it. Try by setting custom headers using curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably means that if there is a host named < script > ... , your function just naively echoes it.

You should filter the output by allowing only valid characters in a host name. Or simply html encode it before echoing.

As a general rule you have to validate all input from un untrusted source like user input.

Often environment variables and http headers are treated as if it would be secure, but it is relatively easy to change them arbitrarily.

Ask yourself where the hostname info is coming from. If it is your dns server, it is unlikely, an attacker could pollute it's cache with such forged host names. If the information comes from a http header it would be very easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  to resolve:
e.g. `<c:out value=request.getRemoteHost() />`